# How to create a bin lengths table in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with species lengths and the observed counts.

```
> df <- data.frame(
+   species = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
+   station = c(1:3,1:3),
+   CLS1 = 11:16,
+   Freq1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,2),
+   CLS2 = c(0, 14, 0, 16,0,17),
+   Freq2 = c(0,1,0,1,0,2),
+   CLS3 = c(0,0,0,18,0,20),
+   Freq3 = c(0,0,0,1,0,1)
+ )
> df
  species station CLS1 Freq1 CLS2 Freq2 CLS3 Freq3
1       A       1   11     1    0     0    0     0
2       A       2   12     1   14     1    0     0
3       A       3   13     1    0     0    0     0
4       B       1   14     1   16     1   18     1
5       B       2   15     1    0     0    0     0
6       B       3   16     2   17     2   20     1
```

`CLS1` stands for the shortest lengths in each obserbation and `Freq1` stands for the frequency that corresponds to it.
If you observe an individual with length greater than `CLS1` at the same station, you would have the values in `CLS2` and `Freq2` or more `CLS3` and `Freq3`.

What I want to have is a bin lengths table like this.
But how can I get this?

```
> cnt_table <- data.frame(
+   species = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
+   station = c(1:3,1:3),
+   X11_12 = c(1,1,0,0,0,0),
+   X13_14 = c(0,1,1,1,0,0),
+   X15_16 = c(0,0,0,1,1,2),
+   X17_18 = c(0,0,0,1,0,0),
+   X19_20 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1)
+ )
> cnt_table
  species station X11_12 X13_14 X15_16 X17_18 X19_20
1       A       1      1      0      0      0      0
2       A       2      1      1      0      0      0
3       A       3      0      1      0      0      0
4       B       1      0      1      1      1      0
5       B       2      0      0      1      0      0
6       B       3      0      0      2      0      1
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified `df` a bit to match your outcome, dplyr solution would be like::

```
df <- data.frame(
 species = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
 station = c(1:3,1:3),
 CLS1 = 11:16,
 Freq1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,2),
 CLS2 = c(0, 14, 0, 16,0,15),
 Freq2 = c(0,1,0,1,0,2),
 CLS3 = c(0,0,0,18,0,20),
 Freq3 = c(0,0,0,1,0,1))
> df
  species station CLS1 Freq1 CLS2 Freq2 CLS3 Freq3
1       A       1   11     1    0     0    0     0
2       A       2   12     1   14     1    0     0
3       A       3   13     1    0     0    0     0
4       B       1   14     1   16     1   18     1
5       B       2   15     1    0     0    0     0
6       B       3   16     2   15     2   20     1

group_1 <- c(11,12)
group_2 <- c(13,14)
group_3 <- c(15,16)
group_4 <- c(17,18)
group_5 <- c(19,20)

> 
> df %>% select(species,station, starts_with("CLS")) %>% 
+   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("CLS")) %>% 
+   mutate(class = case_when(
+     value %in% group_1 ~ "X11_12",
+     value %in% group_2 ~ "X13_14",
+     value %in% group_3 ~ "X15_16",
+     value %in% group_4 ~ "X17_18",
+     value %in% group_5 ~ "X19_20",
+     TRUE ~ "0")) %>%
+   filter(class != "0") %>%
+   group_by(species,station,class) %>%
+   mutate(freq = n()) %>%
+   select(-c(name,value)) %>% 
+   ungroup() %>% distinct() %>%
+   pivot_wider(names_from = class,
+               values_from = freq,
+               values_fill = 0)
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  species station X11_12 X13_14 X15_16 X17_18 X19_20
  <chr>     <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 A             1      1      0      0      0      0
2 A             2      1      1      0      0      0
3 A             3      0      1      0      0      0
4 B             1      0      1      1      1      0
5 B             2      0      0      1      0      0
6 B             3      0      0      2      0      1
```

more elegant solution would be:
from `library(AMR)` we use `age_groups()` just to make nice looking gruops:, you can use `cut()` instead if you like:

```
df_long <- df %>% select(species,station, starts_with("CLS")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("CLS")) %>%
  filter(value !=0) %>% 
  mutate(interval =age_groups(value, split_at = c(11,13,15,17,19,21)))  %>%
  select(-name,-value) %>% droplevels()

ftable(df_long$species ,df_long$station,df_long$interval)


     11-12 13-14 15-16 17-18 19-20
                                  
A 1      1     0     0     0     0
  2      1     1     0     0     0
  3      0     1     0     0     0
B 1      0     1     1     1     0
  2      0     0     1     0     0
  3      0     0     2     0     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I want to take the count data from ```Freq``` column, so not just count the frequency of the value in ```CLS```.  For example, in your data, you have two counts of speciesB with 12cm at station3 as the ```CLS1``` has "12" and the ```Freq1``` has "2". It also has "15" in ```CLS2``` and "2" in ```Freq2```, so in total you would get "4" for ```X14_15``` in the output table.